# importing data from csv into rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> I am trying to import data from CSV into the database using Classes so that I can easily write Test Case for the csv import rake task I created

However, **my solution does not work**.

And I also feel:

1. It doesn't make sense
2. Aside feeling its not a good solution that connotes Ruby mastery, it doesn't work.

Here is what I came up with in my **engines/csv_importer/lib/tasks/csv_import.rake**

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

namespace :csv_import do
  desc 'Import users from csv'

  task users: :environment do
    WebImport.new(url: 'http://blablabla.com/details/people.csv').call.answers
  end
end

class WebImport
  def initialize(url)
    @csv_string = url
  end

  def call
    CSV.parse(@csv_string, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      next unless row[:name].present? && row[:email_address].present?
    end
    CsvImporter::User.create row.to_h
  end

  def self.answers
    user = []
    counter = 0
    duplicate_counter = 0
    user.persisted? ? counter + 1 : duplicate_counter + 1
    p "Email duplicate record: #{user.email_address} - #{user.errors.full_messages.join(',')}" if user.errors.any?
    p "Imported #{counter} users, #{duplicate_counter} duplicate rows ain't added in total"
  end

end
```

**Error when I run rake csv_import:users**

```
$ rake csv_import:users
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: private method `gets' called for {:url=>"http://blablabla.com/details/people.csv"}:Hash
```

How do I **make this work** *and* **write TEST for this** at the long run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are passing a hash to `CSV.parse` while that [method accepts a string](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse).

To fix that you need to change argument from a hash to a string: `WebImport.new('http://blablabla.com/details/people.csv')` and read a remote CSV file before passing it to `CSV.parse`, for example: `CSV.parse(open(url))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
rake db:seed
```

to import the data to your database using seed file as

```
require 'csv'

puts "Importing data..."
CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join("file_name.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
  Model_name.create! do |model_name|
    model_name.name = row[0]
    model_name.email_address = row[1]
  end
end
```

csv file should be in your project root folder